# "Not allowed to load local resource" error is seen while launching the chrome crash url

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I want to crash the chrome url in a separate window for my application testing purpose,
But the below piece of code gives me 'Not allowed to load local resource' error.

Is there any way I can launch the chrome crash url through window.open without receiving the error ?

Here is what I tried :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function crashTest() {                     
            window.open("chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz", "windowInMyApp", "left=50, top=100, width=600, height=400, toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
        }      

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <br />
        <button onclick="crashTest();">Navigate</button>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Web pages can't navigate to `chrome://` URLs [intentionally](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:content/browser/child_process_security_policy_impl.cc;l=624;drc=2f11470d7ad8963a9add116df64d2edd1b85d3a4;bpv=1;bpt=1?sq=package:chromium).
- Normal extension API like chrome.tabs or chrome.windows aren't allowed to open a URL that crashes the browser/renderer process [intentionally](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/extensions/api/tabs/tabs_api.cc;l=485;drc=2f11470d7ad8963a9add116df64d2edd1b85d3a4;bpv=1;bpt=1?sq=package:chromium).

### Solution 1.

A [chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) can send [`Browser.crash`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#method-crash) command via [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger#method-sendCommand) API.

manifest.json excerpt:

```js
"permissions": ["debugger"]
```

browser_action's popup.js or background.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'about:blank', active: false}, ({id: tabId}) => {
  chrome.debugger.attach({tabId}, '1.3', () => {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId}, 'Browser.crash');
  });
});
```

### Solution 2.

The same command can be sent by an external CDP tool like puppeteer ([example](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession)).