# How to close chrome browser window using tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Am trying to close chrome browser windows using tampermonkey but am not getting desire result fully.
the code works when there is time out condition occur , it kill the tab but the 2nd condition where task is completed then `window.close()` is not working and even if task is completed when timeout occur the browser tab get killed. so its very strange issue i not understand why `window.close()` is working it one point and not working it another point , i even swapped both if block up and down but no success. so any idea what am doing wrong.

**my code**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         chromium windows / tab close
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  used by my APP to close chromium browser window
// @author       mee
// @grant        window.close
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var stime = 0;
var timeout = 300; // 5 min

// millis to seconds
function miliseconds_to_seconds(millis) {
  return ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
}

// close browser
function close_browser(){
    // get task progress
    let progress = $("#close_browser").val();
    let kill_it = false;
    
    // check for task time out
    let ctime = performance.now();
    let time_passed = miliseconds_to_seconds(ctime - stime); // in sec
    if(time_passed >= timeout){
        console.log('closing tab time out');
        window.close(); // kill tab ........ WORKING OK
    }
    
    // check if task is completed
    if(progress == 100){
        console.log('closing tab task done');
        window.close(); // kill tab  ............ NOT WORKING 
        timeout = 0; // will force to execute condition 1 but it will not close window till the real timeout is over mean 300 sec.
    }

}

$(document).ready(function() {
       stime = performance.now();
       var intervalID = setInterval(close_browser, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Related: [_"How do I close a firefox tab from a greasemonkey script?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330337/how-do-i-close-a-firefox-tab-from-a-greasemonkey-script)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl my problem is different as you can see i have two conditions 1)  // check for task time out  2) // check if task is completed .  condition 1 successfully close tab/window however condition two is not closing and am not sure why ? there is something wrong with state management as any dynamic conditions not working , static conditions working ok  , example if in condition 2 i do `timeout = 0` then it will still not close window till real 300 seconds are over  . its quite interesting issue can u please look into it.

Comment: window.close() closes the tab where the script runs. It means all scripts are terminated, including yours.

Comment: @wOxxOm ya am executing window.close() through tampermonkey , however its not working under dynamic condition 2 , but its closing window under static condition 1. so am curious why ?

Comment: Like I said, once window.close was called nothing will run afterwards. If you want to exit the browser there are better solutions.

Comment: @wOxxOm am using brave browser the script keep running ever after window.close

`Time Passed : 5  App progress : undefined
Time Passed : 5  App progress : 100
closing tab task done
closing tab time out
Time Passed : 10  App progress : undefined

Time Passed : 10  App progress : 100
closing tab task done
closing tab time out
Time Passed : 15  App progress : undefined

Time Passed : 15  App progress : 100
closing tab task done
closing tab time out
Time Passed : 15  App progress : undefined`

Comment: @wOxxOm can you share other solutions to close browser window/tab . actually my php script on windows server side open brave/chrome browser with specific url and then my JS app do some work  , so i want that close when its finish

Comment: I guess Tampermonkey may be buggy in Brave browser because there's no way a script can run after a successful window.close(). To close the browser I would write an extension ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61745459) - change `crash` to `close`).

Comment: I just tried this in 2021 and Tampermonkey still says it cannot close tabs it didn't open (with Google Chrome anyway).

Comment: ya agree , am using chrome extension for it , my script send close call to it and it close the browser

Answer (score 1):

Tampermonkey now has `// @grant window.close` to allow this action.

Answer (score 0):

Tampermonkey not allowing window.close is a feature to stop scripts like:

```
//@match *://*/*
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.close();
})
```

Comment: And the problem with such script is...? If the user willingly installs it, then why shouldn't it work as expected?